# R - Export dataframe to txt file keeping number format

Tags: r, format, numbers, export, txt

I have a simple 1 column object with many small numbers (tens of thousands), here is a simple example of what it looks like

```
foo <- c(2e-04,0.0099,5e-04,3e-04,0.002,0.0018,6e-04,0.001,3e-04,3e-04,0.005,0.0014,
0.0063,3e-04,0.0054,0.0016,0.0037,0.0071,0.0056,0.0013,0.004,0.0122,0.001,0.0048,
0.0055,0.0039,9e-04,0.004,0.0048,7e-04,0.0013,6e-04,0.0018,0.001,1e-04,6e-04,0.0017,
2e-04,0.0028,0.006,0.0024,0.0026,0.0016,0.0049,0.0043,1e-04,0.0022,4e-04,0.0045,5e-04,
0.0029,3e-04,0.0017,0.0014,0.0078,0.0014,5e-04,0.0081,0.0011,2e-04)
```

I used `formatC` to set the format as follows:

```
foo <- as.numeric(formatC(foo, format = "f", digits = 5, mode = 'real'))
```

Which gives as result `[1] 0.00020 0.00990 0.00050, 0.00030 ...`.

However, when I export using `write.table` the result file has the numbers in scientific notation. I'd like it to stay in the "double" format. I tried using the `formatC` inside `write.table`, but (as expected) it didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah oke, I think I got it, use the format function

```
write.table(format(foo,digits = 5),"outputfile.txt")
```

Comment: @Rob this is the answer I mean

Comment: Hey @BillyBouw, sorry for disapearing. I was away from my computer; I tried it out and it almost works as I wanted. The only problem is that the numbers are saved between quotes, as characters. However I think this is enough for what I want. these are input data to a model in Fortran and I can change from character to float over there. 

Many thanks!

Comment: @PedroAlencar good to hear, would you be so kind to mark my answer as a solution?

Answer (score 0):

the straightforward code works for me

```
write.table(foo,'file.txt')
```

produce a file with content:

```
"x"
"1" 0.00012
"2" 0.00034
"3" 0.00056
"4" 0.07
```